# When i run this code i am getting all the files present in my current directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ....Script by Aravindh kudiyarasan...
array=(alfresco jboss WAS)
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
var=$(ps -ef |grep java |grep -i $i |cut -d"=" -f1)
if [ -n "$var" ]; then
echo *** Application $i is Running ***
fi`enter code here`
done
```

Comment: what about `i=${array[2]}`?

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
echo *** Application $i is Running ***
```

by

```
echo "*** Application $i is Running ***"
```

Comment: Yah now it works ..Now i am getting the expected Thanks for ur quick turn over @ Diego Torres Milano.                                   ....Script by Aravindh kudiyarasan...
*** Application WAS is Running ***